# "Fishmoilapaix"?

Tags: vocabulaire

So I'm still reading *Harry Potter et la Chambre des Secrets*, and I'm at the part where the Weasley brothers are throwing gnomes out of their garden. When picked up, the gnome screams "Fishmoilapaix!" Remembering from reading it in English, I believe he was saying something to the tune of "LemmeAlone!", but I'm trying to figure out what words the French version is pieced together from.

"moilapaix" sounds like "me the peace!" which I'm guessing is part of the French way of saying "Leave me alone!", but what's the "fish"?

Comment: Et voici [une illustration](http://vidberg.blog.lemonde.fr/2012/07/13/la-vente-de-panneaux-solaires-par-telephone/) très parlante… (en version non censurée).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is actually [*fiche*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fiche//3), which is slang for *put* or *don't care*. The phrase [*fiche moi la paix*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ficher_la_paix) is a frozen slang expression for *gimme a rest*, *leave me alone*, *stop pestering me*…

*fishmoilapaix* would be better written *fichmoilapaix*​, which could indeed be translated as *gimmearest* or *lemmealone*.

Comment: Yes I thought it was a very strange translation to use *fish* in place of *fich*, since *sh* does not appear anywhere else in French so far as I have seen.

Answer (score 4):

*Fiche-moi la paix* is equivalent to *buzz off*.