# The meaning and etymology of "histoire de" / "histoire que"?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, étymologie, conjonctions, constructions

Two constructions I've often seen used in French are *histoire de* and *histoire que*, for example:

> Je me promène dans la rue, **histoire de** passer le temps.
>   Tu n'as qu'à amener du vin, **histoire que** tout le monde soit satisfait.

From an answer given to this question, I think I've figured out that these two constructions are basically the same expression, but *histoire de* is used when followed by an infinitive, whereas *histoire que* is used when followed by a verb phrase; in English these roughly translate to "just to [...]" and "just so that [...]".  Therefore, the translations of the above examples are:

> I stroll down the street, **just to** pass the time.
>   You only have to bring some wine, **just so that** everyone will be satisfied.

Am I right in my above reasoning?

And what do these constructions really mean?  Also, how did they come to mean what they do in contemporary French?  They seem rather random.

Answer (score 17):

Both (*histoire de* / *histoire que*) have the same meaning, but they aren't grammatically equivalent.

It's an exact duplicate (meaning and grammar) of *afin de / afin que*, meaning *pour / pour que*.

- **histoire de + [verb at infinitive form]** (*histoire de rigoler*)
- **histoire que + [proposition containing a conjugated verb (subjonctive)]** (*histoire qu'on rigole*)

And it can indeed be translated as *just to* (but *to* or *in order to* could also be adequate)

The [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/histoire) gives these two examples :

> *Je vous les cèderais pour un morceau de pain, **histoire de** vous rendre service* (Courteline, Linottes, Pendule, 1890, p. 182)
>
> ***Histoire que** vous sachiez que je suis homme de parole* (Mérimée, Lettres à Mme de La Rochejacquelein, 1870, p. 200)

---

**- Ajout tardif -** :

Il me semble qu'on peut noter une *autre* différence entre les deux expressions. Seule la variante *histoire de* s'emploie parfois seule, comme une locution dont le sens est volontairement très flou, permettant de s'affranchir d'explications potentiellement longues ou peu utiles. Un exemple sorti du chapeau, à remplacer par un extrait plus authentique si ça vous parait utile :

> « Hé, on pourrait peut-être passer voir si Thierry est rentré de Paris ? *Histoire de*. »

Comment: Globalement d'accord, mais je trouve qu'il y a une touche de dérision dans « histoire de/que » qui n'est absolument pas présente dans « de façon à / pour que » ; et par ailleurs il me semble que « afin de/que » pâtit d'une solennité effrayante. Si j'osais affirmer qu'ils sont équivalents, je mentirais, car je sais sans hésiter choisir laquelle de ces trois possibilités est la plus appropriée.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez +1 C'est juste. La connotation des termes diffère, même si le sens véhiculé est très proche.

Comment: As far as I recall, Romain is from France and it is his first language.....but he doesn't visit Stack Exchange much anymore. Anyone else want to weigh in?

Comment: @Aerovistae The expressions *Histoire de + verbe* and *Histoire que + proposition* convey the same meaning and *Histoire qu'on rigole* is very French, although colloquial. See http://www.crisco.unicaen.fr/IMG/pdf/article_histoire_de.pdf for a research paper about *histoire de* and which mention *histoire que*.

Comment: The paper mentioned in my previous comment is available here https://web.archive.org/web/20180423020530/http://www.crisco.unicaen.fr/IMG/pdf/article_histoire_de.pdf

Answer (score 5):

From personal experience of French, “histoire de” is a shortcut relaxed/informal style for the English “just to”. It conveys the idea of derision (*la route est longue, mangeons des bonbons, histoire de tromper la faim*) ; cynism (*le directeur m'a renvoyée, histoire de montrer qui est le patron*) ; dare (*il a acheté le tout dernier modèle, histoire de prouver qu'il a les moyens*) ; expediency (*le president a fait un démenti par voie de presse, histoire de couper court aux rumeurs*), etc.

Comment: Yeah, but why don't you guys say "Juste pour" or something?  Why the random word "histoire"?

Comment: Exactly @Jez: Quelle est l'histoire de "histoire de"

Answer (score 3):

Seule

> **Histoire de** + ***infinitif*** , expression familière pour marquer le but, l'intention.

est mentionnée dans le Robert.

La *virgule* après histoire : « Histoire, que tu es lente et cruelle ! » change tout le sens.

Je ne suis pas certain que le subjonctif après *histoire que* soit admis par l'académie : une recherche rapide avec « histoire que subjonctif » ne ramène rien.

Cependant, *histoire que* reste une expression argotique contemporaine (ou liée à l'oralité).

#### **Complément**

*Histoire de* semble s'employer lorsque l'on évoque une généralité, lorsque l'on englobe tout le monde :

> Histoire d'en rire, si on faisait une blague à la Grande Duduche ?
> (pour rire de l'effet de la blague en se moquant de la Grande Duduche)
>
> Faisons une blague au premier venu, histoire de rire ! (pour le simple plaisir de rire)

« histoire que nous rions » indiquerait alors une singularité appuyée, un parlé convenu entre personnes de qualité, excluant les personnes extérieures au groupe.

Il semble fonctionner avec *que* lorsque l'intention est comminatoire :

> J'ai voulu faire cette fête, histoire que tu viennes. (familier)
>
> J'ai inventé cette histoire, histoire (répétition intentionnelle à
> la place de *pour*) de vous faire venir. (plus littéraire)

Ajouté comme une sorte d'appogiature, peut faire preuve d'insistance, voir de cynisme selon l'intonation.

> Approche un peu, *histoire que* je t'apprenne les bonnes manières.

*Histoire* peut être :

> Raconte-moi une bonne blague (une ou des histoires), que je rie un
> peu.

sera plus aisé à dire, plus habituel que « histoire que je rie un peu », bien qu'il soit strictement équivalent, tant sur le sens que grammaticalement.

Comment: « histoire que » est contemporaine, oui... mais de Mérimée ;-)

Comment: @RomainVALERI Intéressant, avez-vous la phrase et son contexte : est-ce une phrase littéraire/académique, ou seulement des paroles rapportées?

Comment: oui, c'est l'exemple que j'ai tiré du CNRTL, voir le lien dans ma réponse.

Comment: @RomainVALERI, bravo - Pourtant il me semble qu'en France, l'usage est surtout argotique dans ce troisième millénaire ... à vérifier ... ou à contredire.

Comment: Non, je suis d'accord avec toi : c'est une forme très rare qui serait probablement considérée (à tort ou à raison) comme incorrecte par beaucoup de francophones. A titre personnel, je ne l'emploie jamais, je trouve que ça sonne très mal.

Comment: Je ne vois pas de différence d'usage entre *histoire de* et *histoire que*. Aucun des deux ne sont mentionnés dans le *Dictionnaire de l'Académie*. D'où tires-tu que *histoire que* serait argotique ?

Comment: @Gilles peut-être à cause des dialogues de Coluche, ou des chansonniers? Le Robert ne retient que *'histoire de'*,  et je ne me souviens pas l'avoir vu écrit. La différence d'usage serait écrit/oral, même, si comme je l'ai dit, cela reste subjectif, comme le mentionne aussi Romain.

Comment: @cl-r Des chansonniers comme Courteline et Mérimée ? Je pense que *histoire de/que* est plus utilisé à l'oral qu'à l'écrit, mais ça n'en fait pas un terme argotique. Et encore une fois je ne vois pas de différence d'usage entre *que* et *de*.

Comment: @Gilles Il semble que l'usage ait évolué avec le temps, même si grammaticalement il n'y a aucun différence en soit. Il serait intéressant de savoir cette évolution suit celle de l'emploi du subjonctif.

Answer (score 1):

They are quite equal to me, it's just a slightly different way of saying the same thing.

You could for example say :

> *Tu n'as qu'à amener du vin, histoire de satisfaire tout le monde.*
>
> *Tu n'as qu'à amener du vin, histoire que tout le monde soit satisfait.*

They mean exactly the same.

As for the history of this expression, I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: Tu ne peux pas m'aider avec l'histoire de *histoire de*?  :-)

Comment: Histoire de explains an antecedent and means: Just TO. l'histoire que tout le monde connait is a relative clause.

Answer (score 1):

*histoire de* and *histoire que* get the same meaning as *afin que* (in order to).

For your second sentence, “*tu me donne la paix*” means “*tu me fiches la paix*”. You can find the meaning of this expression in [a previous answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2910/82).

Answer (score 1):

Très intéressant, le sens global et la grammaire est là, mais la "touche de dérision" me semble essentielle. 
Trouver une traduction anglaise qui donnerai la même légèreté / coté comique / cynique / absurde / etc qu'offre l'argot me parait désespéré.

Serait-ce juste une de ces expressions que l'on doit renoncer à traduire avec toute sa drôlerie / charme pour placer une expression porteur de cette drôlerie / charme plus loin dans le texte ?

Dans l'exemple du chef (que j'aime bien), même si je suis fâché par les actions du chef, et impuissant face à lui, j'ai au moins le pouvoir de me moquer de lui et de le ridiculiser gentiment. "Histoire de" permet de montrer que je peux le faire en gardant une certaine légèreté. En anglais, sans une option argotique équivalent, je peux peut-être forcer le trait du coté "sérieux" pour ajouter au coté absurde. Je n'ai pas une traduction en tête, mais une phrase du genre "pince sans rire" ferait peut être l'effet, genre "in order to ascertain his absolutely legitimate authority as chief executive (and master of all)".

"Histoire de rire" might go the opposite way "Have a laugh (or "'Ave a larf")" without the subject or the verb.

Answer (score 1):

"Histoire de" et "Histoire que" constituent la même expression, mais "Histoire de" est suivi d'un verbe à l'infinitif parce que c'est le même sujet qui fait les deux actions dans la phrase. -Je me promène dans la rue, histoire de passer le temps : JE me promène et JE passe le temps.

"Histoire que" est quant à lui suivi d'un verbe au subjonctif parce qu'il y a deux sujets différents qui font les actions des verbes. - Tu n'as qu'à amener du vin, histoire que tout le monde soit satisfait : TU amènes le vin et TOUT LE MONDE est satisfait.

C'est toujours la même règle lorsqu'on utilise ce genre d'articulateur en français, mais dans certains cas, on utilisera l'indicatif à la place du subjonctif. Cela dépend dans ce cas du caractère certain (indicatif) ou incertain (subjonctif) de l'action. Après les articulateurs de but, c'est le subjonctif parce que la réalisation d'un but est incertaine, étant dans le futur par rapport au premier verbe.