# When to use "afin de"/"afin que"?

Tags: prépositions, conjonctions

I can't seem to distinguish *afin que* from *pour que*, or from *afin de*. When are these different conjunctions and preposition used?

Comment: Related: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2945/the-meaning-and-etymology-of-histoire-de-histoire-que

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All have roughly the same purpose, they indicate a goal/reason (*pour*) or a finality (*afin*), but they aren't grammatically equivalent. One must stick to the following constructions:

- *afin de* / *pour* + [verb in infinitive form]
- *afin que* / *pour que* + [clause with a conjugated verb (subjonctive)]
- *pour* + [noun]

Examples:

> Afin qu'il s'améliore.
> Pour qu'il s'améliore.
>
> Afin de résoudre le problème.
> Pour résoudre le problème.
>
> Pour la gloire.

Comment: By the way, “de façon à”, “de manière à”, “histoire de”, “dans le but de” work exactly like “afin de”; and “de façon (à ce) que”, “de manière (à ce) que”, “de sorte que”, “histoire que” work exactly like “afin que”.

Comment: It is literally going to take years to remember all of those in a natural way.

Comment: Hey Stéphane, what's the difference between "de manière que" and "de manière à ce que"? Same with "de façon à ce que." Should I make a question out of this?

Comment: @Aerovistae: It surely deserves its own question. I haven't thought about it and I don't know how to explain the difference.