# “De manière que” vs “de manière à ce que”?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, conjonctions

In the comments under Stéphane's answer to [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3099/when-to-use-afin-de-afin-que/3100?noredirect=1#comment33294_3100), he mentioned the expressions "de manière que" and "de manière à ce que," as well as "de façon que" and "de façon à ce que."

I'm not clear what the difference is between the version that has *à ce* and the version that does not, for each of those two pairs.

Answer (score 2):

- 1 - *De (telle) manière que* →   de (telle) sorte, de façon que.

  > Il a agi de telle manière qu’il a échoué. [Le Robert].
- 2 - *de manière à ce que* (+ conséquence voulue).

  > [Un portique disposé de manière à ce qu'on trouvât de l'ombre à toute heure](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Cva6FlQ-5nYC&pg=PA416&lpg=PA416&dq=Un%20portique%20dispos%C3%A9%20de%20mani%C3%A8re%20%C3%A0%20ce%20qu%27on%20trouv%C3%A2t%20de%20l%27ombre%20%C3%A0%20toute%20heure&source=bl&ots=9hy6ap0GR9&sig=mrNNyItu5GqmmIr_goUUAwRcCO4&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL9vTomd_KAhUH2xoKHRkmBGwQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=Un%20portique%20dispos%C3%A9%20de%20mani%C3%A8re%20%C3%A0%20ce%20qu%27on%20trouv%C3%A2t%20de%20l%27ombre%20%C3%A0%20toute%20heure&f=false) (A. France).

Les usages repérés par *[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de+mani%C3%A8re+que%2Cde+mani%C3%A8re+%C3%A0+ce+que&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cde%20mani%C3%A8re%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cde%20mani%C3%A8re%20%C3%A0%20ce%20que%3B%2Cc0)* indiquent que la première expression  "*De manière que*" était par le passé largement plus utilisée que la seconde.

Le sens est le même pour *de façon (à ce) que*, ou *de manière (à ce) que*, on peut substituer l'un par l'autre. Peut-être une nuance (très subjective) : employer *façon* lorsque l'on *fait* quelque chose, et *manière* pour indiquer la *méthode* utilisée.

L'ajout de *à ce* indique que l'on doit préciser le résultat attendu.

Comment: Tu ne donnes le sens que de la seconde construction.  Si tu renvoies à d'autres expressions qui ont le même genre de double utilisation pour la première construction, ça n'aide pas beaucoup.

Comment: Tu avais choisi le corpus anglais pour ton Ngrams, j'ai rectifié.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez -- Réponse complétée. Pour le Ngram, à chaque fois je me laisse piégé, y a-t-il un moyen de le mettre en français par défaut ?

Comment: Un bon moyen pour s'en rendre compte c'est de vérifier à chaque fois que le nombre d'occurrences est significatif.

Answer (score -1):

Aucun doute, il faut dire: '' De manière à ce que '' l'autre version s'utilise, mais en mauvais français