# Comment « histoire » a-t-il glissé sémantiquement dans « histoire de/que » pour signifier « afin de/que »?

Tags: étymologie

Ni [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/histoire_de) ni [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2945/1995) n'explicite le glissement sémantique.

Answer (score 2):

*Histoire de* est une expression familière relativement récente (XIXe siècle) qui signifie plus précisément "sans autre objectif que celui de".

Sémantiquement, *histoire* signifie ici que l'on fait référence à quelque chose qui est ou qui pourrait arriver. Je ne vois pas de différence **sémantique** fondamentale avec *histoire d'amour*, *histoire drôle*, etc.

Il y a bien sûr une différence grammaticale entre ces utilisations d'*histoire*.

Comment: I don't understand your answer at all. Kindly elaborate? "Sémantiquement, *histoire* signifie ici que l'on fait référence à quelque chose qui est ou qui pourrait arriver." **1. What does this mean?  [I know that etymologically, "history" derives from "story".](https://www.etymonline.com/word/history#etymonline_v_12040) But are you contending that « *histoire* » in this context means "story" in English?**

Comment: "Je ne vois pas de différence fondamentale avec *histoire d'amour, histoire drôle*, etc." **2. With all due respect, how's there no fundamental difference? In English, the "story" in "love story, funny story" can't be used as a conjunction. And in English, "story" doesn't mean "so" or "such" in "so/such that"! I definitely see a fundamental difference in the use of « *histoire* » here! See why I'm befuddled?**

Comment: The fact English specialized the French *histoire* in two different words *story* and *history* doesn't mean *histoire* is required to be translated in one or the other, and whether some word can be used as a conjunction or not has nothing to do with semantics (*le fond*) but with syntax (*la forme*). I still think there is no fundamental semantic difference between *histoire* as used in these examples. There is a grammatical one, granted. Answer updated.

Comment: @user1147844 *histoire* **doesn't mean** "so" or "such", *histoire **de*** does. *histoire **que*** is another way of saying the same thing,  it's a phrase, you can't break it up.  In *faire des histoires*, *histoire* would not translate as "story" either.  Except for very concrete vocabulary, when translating one rarely  has a word for word match. We must think in terms of ideas rather than isolated words.

Comment: @jlliagre Je pense que ce sens d'"histoire" dérive de "Chose, objet auquel on ne sait pas ou ne veut pas donner de nom. " [D1](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/histoire).

Comment: @None Plutôt B2 "B. − L'histoire d'un point de vue individuel, 2. Fam. Ce qui arrive à quelqu'un, ce qui le concerne en particulier; ce qui est fait par quelqu'un." , ce que j'ai indiqué comme *quelque chose qui est arrivé ou qui pourrait arriver*.

Comment: Merci pour vos réponses. 3. But I am bewildered by your comments. "Je ne vois pas de différence sémantique fondamentale avec *histoire d'amour, histoire drôle*, etc" — You are utilizing *histoire* as "story" here (not "history"), correct? Vous ne voyez "pas de différence sémantique fondamentale" — hence you think that *histoire* in *histoire de* means "story" too. I am still befuddled — how's "story" in *histoire* related to "such" in *histoire de* ?

Comment: The idiom ***histoire de*** has a specific meaning but if we try to analyze it, which is often pointless with idioms, the word *histoire* still has one of *histoire* meanings (ce qui arrive à quelqu'un, ce qui est fait par quelqu'un). That's why I believe that that word hasn't fundamentally *glissé sémantiquement*.