# Idiom Involving Histoire

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Here is a passage from a published translation of a popular novel that was originally written in English:

"Je ne mis pas longtemps à transporter mes affaires à l'étage. J'avais la grande chambre à l'ouest, celle qui donnait sur la façade. Elle m'était familière, ayant été mienne depuis ma naissance. Le plancher, les murs bleu clair, le plafond incliné, les rideaux de dentelle jaunie à la fenêtre - tout cela appartenait à mon enfance. Les seuls changements opérés par Charlie au fur et à mesure que j'avais grandi avaient consisté a remplacer le berceau par un lit puis à ajouter un bureau. Sur ce dernier trônait désormais un ordinateur d'occasion, la ligne du modem agrafée le long de la plinthe jusqu'à la prise de téléphone la plus proche. Une exigence de ma mère, **histoire de garder plus facilement le contact**. Le rocking-chair qui avait bercé ma prime jeunesse était toujours dans la même coin."

I have added the boldfacing emphasis.

My question is, what is the word "histoire" doing there? The sense of the passage is clear, but the function of "histoire" in the sentence is obscure to me. Is this an example of some French idiom? Any commonly encountered examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the English text from which this is translated?

Comment: See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33825/histoire-de-se-changer-les-id%c3%a9es-what-exactly-is-this-saying

Comment: @LPH: "The desk now held a secondhand computer, with the phone line for the modem stapled along 
the floor to the nearest phone jack. This was a stipulation from my mother, so that we could stay in touch 
easily." (The full paragraph is too long.)

Comment: So "histoire de" renders "so as to"; however I think it does not imply the connotations that can be found in "histoire de". For details see the answer I give here https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37707/17649.