# On utilise « histoire de » à quel point souvent pour dire « just because » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Elle veut dire quoi l’expression « histoire de » en fin de phrase ? Est-ce que c’est comme notre « just because » ?

« Je suis allé au centre commercial, histoire de. »

Answer (score 3):

Here, ***histoire de*** means that going to the shopping mall was a possibility and you decided to do it, just for the xxxx of it, or just for yyyy it.

Xxxx or yyyy are not specified but what is suggested is that going there was done neither enthusiastically nor reluctantly.

That might match the English "**just because**" or "**just to do it**".

---

Ici, ***histoire de*** signifie qu'aller au centre commercial était une éventualité et qu'on a décidé d'y aller, juste comme ça.

On ne donne pas d'explication sur les raisons ou les objectifs mais l'absence de suite à la préposition ***de*** suggère que ce n'était fait ni de manière enthousiaste, ni a contrecœur.

Il est possible que ça corresponde à l'anglais "**just because**" ou "**just to do it**".

---

See also/voir aussi:

- [The meaning and etymology of "histoire de" / "histoire que"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2945/the-meaning-and-etymology-of-histoire-de-histoire-que)
- http://www.academie-francaise.fr/histoire-de-au-sens-de-pour

Answer (score 2):

Il s'agit d'un usage moderne ; c'est le résultat d'une pensée atrophié, le résultat d'un emprunt à la langue de locuteurs qui par le passé ajoutaient quelque chose de leur cru après « histoire de », ce que les locuteurs modernes continuent de faire ;  voilà des exemples de l'utilisation de l'expression normale, la définition du TLFi montrant que « histoire de » a une valeur de préposition ;

> (TLFi) Loc. prép. Histoire de + inf. Pour, afin de
>
> - Je vous les cèderais pour un morceau de pain, histoire de vous rendre service.

- J'ai acheté ça histoire de ne pas lui avoir pris son temps pour rien.
- Elle lui a dit cela histoire de rire, mais pas plus.
- Ils l'ont questionné histoire de savoir s'il mentait mais sans intérêt pour la vérité.

L'[internaute](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/19411/histoire-de/) ajoute une définition intéressante : il n'est plus question d'une locution prépositionnelle mais d'une locution qui contient une préposition et la signification est « **simplement** pour ».

Utiliser « histoire de » en fin de phrase revient à utiliser « afin de » ou « pour » en fin de phrase. On ne trouve aucune trace de cet usage dans les sources suivantes : [reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/histoire%20de), [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/histoire_de), [internaute](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/19411/histoire-de/).

On trouve une trace de cet usage moderne dans [Word reference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/comme-%C3%A7a-histoire-de.3121559/), et la signification est « comme ça » ; cela veut dire que la personne qui parle ne sait pas vraiment pourquoi elle a fait ce dont elle vient de parler dans la même phrase.